# Webkit-sharp example applications

Tags: mono, webkit

Could anybody suggest a good open source (as in I can see the source, license irrelevant) webkit-sharp-based application? I've been wanting to jump into development with webkit-sharp and gtk-sharp, but I haven't found much of any documentation on webkit-sharp. I thought a good application example is as good as any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody else that has this issue, a good application I just found is the sample app included with the source. For anybody answering, I didn't think about checking the source for samples when I posted this. The name of the sample is called FunnyBrowser.cs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine:
https://github.com/dmulder/owa_browse

There don't seem to be many examples around of anyone using this. I've been looking through the docs at http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable to figure it out.